# Two classes with the same name in different files?

Tags: swift, enums, encapsulation

I have no idea if this is even possible, or if I should be doing something like this.

Example two different files, same enum:

**Counter.swift**

```
enum Action {
   case Increment
   case Decrement
}
```

**Counterpair.swift**

```
enum Action {  // invalid redeclaration of 'Action'
   case Reset
   case Top(Action) // Action should be Counter.Action
   case Bottom(Action) // same
}
```

I am coming from javascript, there you could just do `Counter.Action` after a `require(Counterpair)`.

How do I structure my application in a way that Counter or Counterpair (or whatever other module) could describe an enum Action without breaking encapsulation?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are already exposed to the module terminology. In Swift, you don't import just a single file. You can only import other modules (examples would be frameworks like Foundation, UIKit, CoreData, etc). Basically, what this means is all the files in your project form a single module. Because they are all part of the same module, all of your files have visibility to each other in your project. You can use the Access Control features of Swift to set what part of your files are visible to each other, or to other modules that import your code.

The simplest and easiest fix to your situation is to simply come up with two different names for your enums.

```
enum Behavior {
   case Increment
   case Decrement
}

enum Action {
   case Reset
   case Top(Behavior)
   case Bottom(Behavior)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Thanks!
Is there any way of writing something like this:
```enum Counter: Action {
   case Increment
   case Decrement
}
```
Is it possible to define something like this? It would be quite handy if all these enums are of a 'type' Action, because I have a ```update```-function which takes an ```Action enum``` and matches them with a switch case...

Comment: There certainly could be a way to elegantly handle the behavior you need, but without more context, I am afraid I am having trouble coming up with something. Your `enum Counter: Action { case Increment case Decrement }` example would mean the Counter enum implements the Action protocol. Could you perhaps explain the relationship between Incrementing/Decrementing and the Reset/Top/Bottom actions?

Comment: I have a model which contains all the state of my app. The only way to update the model is by dispatching an ```Action```. Basically after dispatching an ```Action```, it reaches a composed ```func update(action: Action, model: Model) -> Model { switch action {//calculate next state and return it }}```. I could be using Strings in the switch case to check the action, but Enums look like the perfect use case here... Problem is there will be many ```Actions``` in my whole app, I want to split them somehow and still use the update func w/ an enum of 'type Action' as parameter.